# Virtualenv : Getting error while

Tags: ubuntu, virtualenv, virtualenvwrapper

```
$  virtualenv envv
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/rohit/bin/virtualenv", line 5, in <module>
    from pkg_resources import load_entry_point
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pkg_resources.py", line 2880, in <module>
    parse_requirements(__requires__), Environment()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pkg_resources.py", line 596, in resolve
    raise DistributionNotFound(req)
pkg_resources.DistributionNotFound: virtualenv==1.9.1
```

Reinstalled through synaptic package but getting same issue. Kindly help

Answer (score 0):

I cleared the packages in the specific folder mentioned in the error and reinstalled with command

```
pip install virtualenv
```

Simple as that